# Actionscript 3: hitTestObject inside classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, hittest

When I click on a car (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN) the car disappears and the function verlaagLevens() is executed. This works (but I put in it comments though)

Now, instead of the clickevent, I want to detect a hitTestObject between my Ship and the same Car, but it doesn't seem to be working. 
This is my Car-class:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Car extends MovieClip
{
    //private var hit:uint = 0;
    private var mySpeed:uint = 0;
    private var target:Ship;
    private var stageRef:Stage;
    public static var instance2:Car;

    public function Car(stageRef:Stage, target:Ship) {
        instance2 = this;
        this.x = x;
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        this.target = target;
        mySpeed = 10;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, beweeg);
        reset();

    }
    public function reset() {
        if(Main.end_def == 0){
        this.y =0-100/Math.random();
        this.x = Math.random()*(1+300-60)+60;
        }
        //hit = 0;

    }
    public function getroffen() {

        Main.instance.verlaagLevens();
        this.parent.removeChild(this);

    }


    public function beweeg(evt:Event):void {
        if (hitTestObject(target.hit))
        {
            trace("hitTest");
            getroffen();
            reset();
        }
        this.y += mySpeed;
        if (this.y>480) {
            reset();
        }

    }


}
```

}

And this is my Main-class:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {

        private var aantaltegenliggers:uint = 5;
        private var _levens:uint = 3;
        var ourShip:Ship = new Ship(stage);
        public static var instance:Main;
        var car:MovieClip;
        var end = 0;
        public static var end_def:uint;


        public function Main()
        {
            stop();
            instance = this;
        }

        public function initGame():void
        {
            //add it to the display list
            stage.addChild(ourShip);
            ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 1.3;

            _levens=3;
            end_def=0;
            teken_levens();


            for (var i:uint=0; i<aantaltegenliggers; i++) 
                {
                    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);
                    myTimer.start();
                    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent){


                    if (end==0){
                    car = new Car(stage, ourShip);
                    car.name = "car"+i;
                    //car.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,getroffen);
                    car.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,gameover);
                    stage.addChild(car);

                    }
                    });


            }

        }
            public function verlaagLevens():void 
            {
                verwijder_een_leven(_levens);
                _levens--;
            }
            // één leven tekenen
            public function teken_een_leven(levenIndex:uint):void 
            {
                var leven:MovieClip = new Leven(); // linkage - export voor Actionscript
                leven.x = levenIndex*35; // positie leven in de x as, 35 pixels opschuiven
                leven.y = 10; // positie leven in de y as
                leven.name = "leven"+levenIndex;
                addChild(leven);    // één leven tonen op het scherm
            }
            // alle levens tekenen
            public function teken_levens():void 
            {
                verwijder_levens(); // verwijder één leven als je de missile niet hebt kunnen raken
                for (var i:uint=1; i<=_levens; i++) 
                {
                    teken_een_leven(i);
                }
            }
            // een leven van het scherm verwijderen
            public function verwijder_een_leven(levenIndex:uint):void 
            {
                if (!(getChildByName("leven"+levenIndex)==null) ) 
                {  // ! is negatie = logische operator
                    removeChild(getChildByName("leven"+levenIndex));
                }
            }
            // alle levens verwijderen
            public function verwijder_levens():void 
            {
                for (var i:uint=1; i<=_levens; i++) 
                {
                    verwijder_een_leven(i);
                }
            }

            public function gameover(evt:Event):void 
            {
                if(_levens==0)
                {   
                    if(end_def == 0){
                    end = 1;
                    stage.removeChild(ourShip);
                    gotoAndStop("gameover");
                    }
                    end_def=1;
                }
            }



    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not very good at actionscript so there could be a few mistakes, I really would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are performing your hit test in Car's constructor, which is only called one time. 
What you probably want (since cars move) is to check for a collision every frame, in your begween function.
(This is also assuming target.hit is correct, I can't tell since I don't have access to your Ship but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt).

Comment: Ok, that's something The hittest is detected and traced. Now my function beweeg() looks like this: 

public function beweeg(evt:Event):void {
   if (hitTestObject(target.hit))
   {
     trace("hitTest");
     //getroffen();
   }
   this.y += mySpeed;
   if (this.y>480) {
    reset();
   }

But when I remove getroffen(); from comments I get an error though: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, that's not possible when adding a comment

Comment: I think the problem lies in this.parent.removeChild(this); When I debug, that's the error that comes up

Comment: You can edit your original post to show the change. Also you want to remove the event listeners from the car. Even though it has been removed from the stage these events will still fire.
Next I would go into main and try commenting out lines following the path that will be called, not sure what line the error is coming from

Comment: trace this.parent instead of the removechild